# How could I make .jpg files don't use the QGIS icon

Tags: qgis, jpg, icon

I'm a bit perfectionist and the QGIS have a annoying little problem: it changes all of my .jpeg and .jpg icons to QGIS file icons. I would like to change that, but I have no idea.

I use Linux Minx XFCE.

Comment: I guess this is an OS-specific issue. A software you install tends to set certain extensions to open by itself. So, OS changes the icon of extension to the software's icon. But it is weird that QGIS changes all of .jpeg icons to QGIS file icons, though.

Comment: Was .jpg file extension associated to another app before QGIS?

Answer (score 7):

> 1. Right-click on any file with the desired file type or extension, choose “Properties” from the context menu.
> 2. The “Properties” dialog appears. Click on the “Open With” tab.
> 3. Select the desired application for the given file type. All files with the same extension will now be opened with this program by
>    default and file icons will be changed.
>
> [image]
>
> Set the default program for a given file type / extension (Here a pdf
> document in Nemo on Linux Mint)
>
> On Linux Mint, replace step one and two choosing “Open With” → “Other
> Application…” in the contextual menu, as seen in the picture above.

Reference: [How to change the default application for a type of file on Linux](https://libre-software.net/change-the-default-application-linux-mint-ubuntu/)